# Copy non python files via package_data to Scripts directory

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I have some scripts in my package, that rely on some template xml files.
Those scripts are callable by entry points and I wanted to reference the template files by a relative path.

When calling the script via `python -m ...` the scripts themselves are called from within `lib\site-packages` and there the xml files are available as I put them in my `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=['my_pck'],
    package_dir={'my_pck': 'python/src/my_pck'},
    package_data={'my_pck': ['reports/templates/*.xml']},
    ...
)
```

I know, I could copy those templates also by using `data_files` in my `setup.py` but using `package_data` seems better to me.

Unfortunately `package_data` seems not to copy those files to the `Scripts` folder where the entry points are located.

So my question is, is this even achievable via `package_data` and if, how?
Or is there a more pythonic, easier way to achieve this? Maybe not referencing those files via paths relative to the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [importlib-resources](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#using) might help here. This library is able to find the actual path to a resource file packaged as `package_data` by `setuptools`.

Access the `package_data` files from your code with something like this:

```
with importlib_resources.path('my_pck.reports.templates', 'a.xml') as xml_path:
    do_something(xml_path)
```

Comment: @Igle Does that help? Anything else that would need to be clarified?